# Join datetimediff SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to get a date time diff between two fields and join them on the condition that val equals 1 or val equals 0. I have this query to get the values and would like to add a subquery to get the diff. Would it be easier to do this in a subquery or a new query?

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
     TagName     VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     Value       BIT  NOT NULL,
     Status      VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
     DateAndTime VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL,
     Val         BIT  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mytable(TagName, Value, Status, DateAndTime, Val) 
VALUES ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 12:48:47.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 12:43:52.000',0),   
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 12:41:06.000',1),  
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 12:36:21.000',0),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 12:34:05.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 12:29:13.000',0),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 12:26:23.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 12:21:27.000',0),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 12:19:12.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 12:13:59.000',0),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 12:11:11.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 12:06:12.000',0),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 12:04:03.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 11:58:53.000',0),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 11:56:02.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 11:51:03.000',0),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 11:48:49.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 11:43:45.000',0),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 11:40:59.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 11:36:02.000',0),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 11:33:39.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 11:28:20.000',0),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 11:25:35.000',1),
       ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 11:20:16.000',0);
INSERT INTO mytable(TagName,Value,Status,DateAndTime,Val) VALUES ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 11:18:06.000',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(TagName,Value,Status,DateAndTime,Val) VALUES ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 11:12:55.000',0);
INSERT INTO mytable(TagName,Value,Status,DateAndTime,Val) VALUES ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P2_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 11:10:12.000',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(TagName,Value,Status,DateAndTime,Val) VALUES ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',0,'OFF','2018-01-09 11:04:44.000',0);
INSERT INTO mytable(TagName,Value,Status,DateAndTime,Val) VALUES ('LIFT_STA\EASTS\S35_P1_RUN',1,'RUNNING','2018-01-09 11:02:35.000',1);

SELECT TOP 1000 
    TagTable.TagName,
    DigitalTagDescription.VALUE,
    DigitalTagDescription.[Status],
    [DateAndTime],
    [Val]  
FROM 
    [TS_SCADA_DIGITAL].[dbo].[FloatValues]
INNER JOIN 
    TS_SCADA_DIGITAL.dbo.TagTable ON TagTable.TagIndex = FloatValues.TagIndex
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[DigitalTagDescription] ON DigitalTagDescription.TAG_NAME = TagTable.TagName And DigitalTagDescription.Value = FloatValues.Val
WHERE
    FloatValues.DateAndTime > Cast(GETDATE() as Date) 
    AND DigitalTagDescription.TAG_NAME LIKE 'Lift_STA\EASTS%'
ORDER BY
    DateAndTime DESC
```

```
+------------------------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------+
| TagName | Value  |Status |  DateAndTime              | Val|  DateTimeDiff |            
+------------------------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  P1_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 12:48:47.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 12:43:52.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 12:41:06.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 12:36:21.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 12:34:05.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 12:29:13.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 12:26:23.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 12:21:27.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 12:19:12.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 12:13:59.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 12:11:11.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 12:06:12.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 12:04:03.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 11:58:53.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 11:56:02.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 11:51:03.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 11:48:49.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 11:43:45.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 11:40:59.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 11:36:02.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 11:33:39.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 11:28:20.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 11:25:35.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 11:20:16.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 11:18:06.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 11:12:55.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P2_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 11:10:12.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 0 | 'OFF'     | '2018-01-09 11:04:44.000' | 0)|  DateDiffHere  |
|  P1_RUN' | 1 | 'RUNNING' | '2018-01-09 11:02:35.000' | 1)|  DateDiffHere  |
+------------------------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: You can group by `TagTable.TagName` and use case statement to get values for start and end `DateAndTime` columns and then use those columns to get the difference.

Comment: Instead of pictures it is better to post actual details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thank you I will try this and hope it makes it more clear

Comment: Is this better or should i add more?

Comment: `I need to get a date time diff between two fields` I only see one date time field. Perhaps you meant you want the diff between two rows? If so which rows? The preceding row?

Comment: Yes i apologize. I need to get the time diff between running and off during each cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer i ended up with. The use of the Lag() and Lead() functions encapsulate all the logic of “reaching” back or forward respectively by any number of rows.

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 CONVERT(char(10), [DateAndTime], 108) as Time ,
                tagtable.tagname, 
                digitaltagdescription.value, 
                digitaltagdescription.[status], 



                    CASE  digitaltagdescription.[STATUS] 
 WHEN 'Off' THEN 
 DATEDIFF(minute, Lag([DateAndTime], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [TagName], [DateAndTime]), [DateAndTime])
 ELSE 
 NULL
END RunTime





FROM   [TS_SCADA_DIGITAL].[dbo].[floatvalues] 
       INNER JOIN ts_scada_digital.dbo.tagtable 
               ON tagtable.tagindex = floatvalues.tagindex 
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[digitaltagdescription] 
               ON digitaltagdescription.tag_name = tagtable.tagname 
                  AND digitaltagdescription.value = floatvalues.val 




WHERE  floatvalues.dateandtime > Cast(Getdate() AS DATE) 
       AND digitaltagdescription.tag_name LIKE 'Lift_STA\EASTS%' 





ORDER  BY dateandtime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines...Hope you get the idea. If you can post some details then I can get you a better answer.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 tagtable.tagname, 
                digitaltagdescription.value, 
                digitaltagdescription.[status], 
                [val], 
                Max(CASE digitaltagdescription.value 
                      WHEN 1 THEN [dateandtime] 
                      ELSE NULL 
                    END) StartTime, 
                Max(CASE digitaltagdescription.value 
                      WHEN 0 THEN [dateandtime] 
                      ELSE NULL 
                    END) EndTime 
FROM   [TS_SCADA_DIGITAL].[dbo].[floatvalues] 
       INNER JOIN ts_scada_digital.dbo.tagtable 
               ON tagtable.tagindex = floatvalues.tagindex 
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[digitaltagdescription] 
               ON digitaltagdescription.tag_name = tagtable.tagname 
                  AND digitaltagdescription.value = floatvalues.val 
WHERE  floatvalues.dateandtime > Cast(Getdate() AS DATE) 
       AND digitaltagdescription.tag_name LIKE 'Lift_STA\EASTS%' 
GROUP  BY tagtable.tagname 
ORDER  BY dateandtime DESC
```

From this query, you can use the start and end time to get the difference as needed. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You can't just arbitrarily decide to group by a single column. This would result in an error message that the column value, status and val are not allowed in the select list because they are not contained in a group by or aggregate.

Comment: This is not meant to be a solution. Just a guideline. Any non aggregate columns would need to be added to the group by and adjusted. The point I was trying to convey was to use the case statement.